# Downloaded music plays on PC and transfers to phone, but some files don't show up in phone library after transfer

Tags: music, file-transfer

My music - which is in MP3 format - plays normally on my PC. When I transfer some of my music to my device, my computer says the transfer was complete, however I cannot see some of the music on my device. Why are some songs not appearing in my phone's music library?

Comment: I thank you for your help I will check the format again on these songs it may be one not supported

Answer (score 1):

Please reboot your device.

Once you have rebooted, the music will show up in your music app.

When you boot, Android searched all SD Cards for media, and then adds it to the media database, so that media apps can use it.

Please reboot, and the music will then show in your music player.

If you *have* already rebooted, then please clear the data for the following apps:

- Media Storage
- Music (or Music Player, or Media Player)

If that still doesn't work, then copy the music direct to the music folder of the SD Card that is in your device.

Final thing - Android doesn't support ALL music formats. If the file is in a format Android doesn't support, then it won't show in the Music app.

Comment: MP3 files and when I rebooted they still did not show up

Comment: @donnybrookit MP3

Comment: @donnybrookit MP3 files are definitely supported. Please follow the steps above to reset the media apps. If that doesn't work, I suggest you use a file manager app to see if they transferred to your device or not.

Comment: @ LiamW WILL DO